# Listen to single and double click event on single vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I tried searching online though I did find an answer which is this one -> https://antenna.io/blog/2018/03/handle-single-and-double-clicks-on-the-same-element-in-vue-js/

but couldn't understand it so I can up with a solution inspired by above solution

```
 detectClick() {
  this.clickCount += 1;
  if (this.clickCount === 1) {
    var singleClick = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("we are in singleClick");
      this.currentPickerDate();
      this.clickCount = 0;
    }, 500);
  }
  if (this.clickCount === 2) {
    console.log("we are in double Click");
    clearTimeout(singleClick);
    this.showEvent();
    this.clickCount = 0;
  }
}
```

and the component is

```
<v-date-picker
    v-model="date"
    @click:date="detectClick"
    :events="allEvents"
    :picker-date.sync="pickerDate"
    event-color="red lighten-2">
</v-date-picker>
```

I don't think currentPickerFunction is required but if you do need it let me know
In detectClick function the problem is that my setTimeout function is not working i don't know why If you know a better answer let me know Thanks

I am using vue 2 and vuetify

Answer (score 1):

`@click` - single click

`@dblclick` - double click

Edit: never mind, i misread the question

Answer (score 0):

Because `var singleClick` is defined in the first if clause, it has block scope. Therefore, `singleClick` can not be accessed in the second if clause. You must define `singleClick` in global scope. You can see that `clickTimer: null` has been defined in `data()` if you look at the [link](https://antenna.io/blog/2018/03/handle-single-and-double-clicks-on-the-same-element-in-vue-js/) that you have shared:

```
data () {
   return {
      clickCount: 0,
      clickTimer: null
   };
},
```

Check out the [link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) about javascript scope